# Which command button called a sub?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the same command button called "Output" on many sheets in the same workbook.  All of the buttons call the same "sub Output()" in module ModMain.  I need to know what sheet the command call came from?

Comment: You can add a parameter that identifies it.

Comment: If you are clicking a button on the sheet, then it will always be the active sheet.  So the code would be something like `MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name`

Comment: As an alternative (useful if you have multiple buttons on the same sheet) you can look at `Application.Caller`, which returns the name of the button which was clicked: if you name your buttons uniquely you can then determine how to handle the call.

Comment: Tim Williams, That is what I was looking for!  Thank you!  I renamed all of the Buttons to the Name of their Tab and now I know where the command came from and I can use that to tell the procedure which picture (Pictures are also named after the Tab they are on) to find using a for/Next loop of the sheet Shapes and copy it to the Output sheet.

Comment: Worth also noting that (using a Forms button on a worksheet) you can pass parameters via the "onAction" setting, so if you enter (eg) `'TestSub "Hello", 2'` into the "macro name" textbox (including the single-quotes) that will call `TestSub` and pass `"Hello"` and `2` as parameters.

Comment: @TimWilliams, why don't you add this as an answer so it can be selected as the solution and the question marked as answered.

Answer (score 4):

One approach (particularly useful if you have multiple buttons on the same sheet all calling the same procedure) you can use is to look at the value of

```
Application.Caller
```

in your called Sub.  This returns the name of the button which was clicked: if you name your buttons uniquely you can then determine how to handle the call.

Worth also noting that (using a Forms button on a worksheet) you can pass parameters via the "onAction" setting, so if you enter (eg)

```
'TestSub "Hello", 2'
```

into the "macro name" textbox (including the single-quotes) that will call TestSub and pass "Hello" and 2 as parameters.

Comment: Good explanation available at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx (scroll 1/3 down)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure this is at the top of every VBA module:

```
Option Explicit
```

Then change this:

```
Sub Output()
```

to this:

```
Sub Output(strSource as String)
```

You have added an argument to the `Sub`.  Now your code will fail to compile.  (Refer to help if you don't know this part.)

Fix the code so it compiles.  The VBA editor will direct you to every location.   Those locations will be the VBA procedures for your "all the same" buttons.

Where each calls `Output`, change it to `Output("ThisPlace")`.  For *this place*, insert a unique name as identifier.

Now the button is identified in a way you can grab from within the `Sub`.